Connection between $R^2$ and Mutual Information
Interpreting MI as "the amount of uncertainty removed by adding some information", I would expect some connection to $R^2$, which is the "amount of variance explained by adding some information".
In particular, $I(X,Y) = H(Y)-H(Y|X)$, which, poorly rephrased, is, "how uncertain you are about $Y$ to begin with" - "how uncertain you are about $Y$ after you got to know $X$"
On the other hand, $R^2 = 1-\frac{\sum (y_i - f(x_i))^2}{\sum (y_i - \bar{y})^2}$, which, to me, maybe wrongly, is sort of assuming that $p(Y|X) \sim N(0, \sigma_1^2)$ where $\sigma_1^2 = N^{-1}\sum (y_i - f(x_i))^2$ and $p(Y)\sim N(0, \sigma_2^2)$ where $\sigma_2^2 = N^{-1}\sum (y_i - \bar{y})^2$... which leaves us with $R^2 = 1-E_x[Var[p(y|x)]]/Var[p(y)]$
Now, if we define $\hat{R^2} = \frac{Var[p(y)]}{E_x[Var[p(y|x)]]} \propto R^2$ (proportional in a non-linear way), I'd say it looks like that:
$$
I(X,Y) \stackrel{?}{=} \alpha\ln \hat{R^2} =  \alpha(\ln(Var[p(y)]) -\ln(E_x[Var[p(y|x)]])),\,\, \text{for some }\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^+
$$
And indeed, the entropy of a Gaussian distribution is $\ln c\sigma^2$
So in other words, it seems like there is indeed a connection between $R^2$ (or at least, its made up brother $\hat{R^2}$) and Mutual Information, if we assume $p(y)$ and $p(y|x)$ to be Gaussian
Am I doing something wrong/saying something that is just made up?

This question is similar to: Relationship between least-squares regression and information theory. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@User1865345 am i missing something or nowhere in that post R^2 is even mentioned?

I see this as related to, but not a duplicate of, the link.

Firstly, mutual information is a measure of statistical dependence between random variables, whereas $R^2$ is a measure of goodness-of-fit. In other words, $I(X;Y)$ is intrinsic to the data, whereas $R^2$ is defined with respect to a predictive model ($f$ in your notation). So they aren't quite directly comparable.
However, for the case of simple linear regression, if $X, Y$ are jointly Gaussian, $R^2$ and $I(X; Y)$ are related.
For Gaussian random variables with correlation $\rho$
$$I(X; Y) = -\frac{1}{2} \log (1-\rho^2)$$
(see Thomas & Cover chapter 8, eqn. 8.52 for details)
And the $R^2$ should be $\rho^2$.
More generally, $I(X;Y)$ can be used to construct an upper bound on $R^2$. This reasoning applies for non-Gaussian data and any choice of $f$. Starting from your observation that
$$R^2 = 1 - \frac{\mathbb{E}[(Y-f(X))^2]}{\mathbb{E}[(Y - \mathbb{E}(Y))^2]}$$
$$\leq 1 - \frac{\text{Var}(Y|X)}{\text{Var}(Y)}$$
we can note that the maximum entropy distribution with fixed variance is a Gaussian, so
$$R^2 \leq 1 - \frac{e^{2 h(Y|X)}}{2\pi e \text{Var}(X)}$$
$$= 1 - \frac{e^{2(h(Y) - I(X;Y))}}{2\pi e \text{Var}(X)}$$
Hope this helps!!

lovely i’d say!
